# CGI post form with jQuery not fully loaded

Tags: jquery, c++

I'm trying to write a C++ CGI program that gives a jQuery Mobile response with multiple pages.  However, it seems that only the first  from the response is being processed (have tried multiple browsers).

To simplify, I have created the following HTML page with a simple form using Post to call the CGI program:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">    
    <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/testForm">
      <center>
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Login">
      </center>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The C++ code for testForm is:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc,char**argv,char**environ) {
   printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n");

   printf("<html>\n");
   printf("<head>\n");
   printf("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n");
   printf("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css\">\n");
   printf("<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js\"></script>\n");
   printf("<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js\"></script>\n");
   printf("</head>\n\n");
   printf("<body>\n\n");
   printf("<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page1\">\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"header\">\n");
   printf("    <h1>Page1</h1>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"main\" class=\"ui-content\">\n");
   printf("    <p>text</p>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"footer\">\n");
   printf("    <div data-role=\"navbar\">\n");
   printf("      <ul>\n");
   printf("        <li><a href=\"#page1\">Page1</a></li>\n");
   printf("        <li><a href=\"#page2\">Page2</a></li>\n");
   printf("      </ul>\n");
   printf("    </div>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("</div>\n\n");
   printf("<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page2\">\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"header\">\n");
   printf("    <h1>Page2</h1>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"main\" class=\"ui-content\">\n");
   printf("    <p>text</p>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("  <div data-role=\"footer\">\n");
   printf("    <div data-role=\"navbar\">\n");
   printf("      <ul>\n");
   printf("        <li><a href=\"#page1\">Page1</a></li>\n");
   printf("        <li><a href=\"#page2\">Page2</a></li>\n");
   printf("      </ul>\n");
   printf("    </div>\n");
   printf("  </div>\n");
   printf("</div>\n\n");
   printf("</body>\n");
   printf("</html>\n");
   return 0;
}
```

When I run this through the "Post" form, I am unable to navigate to page2, and a "view source" in Safari indicates that only the div for the first page was processed.

Interestingly, if I hit reload, it loads the form using "get" and both pages are loaded correctly.

Is there some limitation of CGI programs using "post" from having multiple pages processed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CGI or POST requests.
This is jQuery's doing.

If you open your HTML page, open Dev Tools and go to the Network tab (in Safari: Timelines > Network Requests) and then hit the "Login" button, it becomes evident that jQuery converts the form submission to an XHR, integrates the response back into the current page and hacks the URL displayed in the browser bar somehow.
After that, all `#`-links on the page seem to be broken, thus also breaking jQuery's page navigation, which relies on such links.

Now, I have no clue why that is actually happening, but here's one way of fixing it:

Tell jQuery to not convert form submissions to XHRs.
You can do so by adding `data-ajax="false"` to your `<form>` tag.